# Firefox extension creating different instance for two windows

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I created a Firefox extension and chrome extension. In Chrome I am using background.cs, so it will get loaded only once for all Chrome instances, so if I will write simple alert in background it will show alert box only for once.

The same thing is not working with Firefox, it will show that alert message all the times when I will open new Firefox windows.

Is there anything like background in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Either write a [javascript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FUsing) or switch to the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/)

A javascript module would be something like this

```js
this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Helper"];

this Helper = {
  initialized: false,
  init: function() {
    if(this.initialized){
      return;
    }
    // code here is executed only the first time init() is called
    this.initialized = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am not able to get it.
Like, Simple not I want to create on object, which should initialize an object only for first instance, not for every new firefox window.